# Extract array from string

Tags: python

I have a string that looks like this:

```
arr = "[[[234],[432], ..., [523]]]"
```

I want to extract the array in this string so that it becomes:

```
arr = [[[234], [432], ..., [523]]]
```

how do I go about doing this?

Comment: For simple data like that there is `ast.literal_eval`. For more complex things there is the **very dangerous** `eval`.

Comment: Are the `...` part of string or just a placeholder? if it's the latter, did you try *ast.literal\_eval*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping away from [dangers of eval](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) you can use  [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
ast.literal_eval("[[[234],[432],[523]]]") #[[[234], [432], [523]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
arr = "[[[234],[432], [523]]]"

arr = eval(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `eval()` function of python.

```
>>> arr=eval("[[[234],[432],[523]]]")
>>> arr
[[[234], [432], [523]]]
```